# Auto update cases after time x

Tags: visual-workflow, automation, time-dependent-workflow, scheduled-flow

I asked this before, but this time with a different approach (same goal though)
After 5 days a case (with a specific record type to avoid the dml limit and also only getting the preferred cases) should get set the status back to open (nothing more) when the LastModifiedDate is greater or equal to 5 days ago.

I created a formula date field which already gives me the correct date in the future

[image]

So my idea would be to have an scheduled trigger flow running every day and jus looking for this field. And if the `{!$Flow.CurrentDate}` value matches the field value then update the case.

Question to all the pros out there: Would that work?

[image]

Kind regards
Alex

---

Thanks for the answer so far. I created a record trigger with a scheduled path. Not sure if this is correct:

[image]
Also some entry filters:
[image]
and a single get item
[image]
When I save it and debug it there is an error message:
Nothing is connected to the Start-Element.
Which I tend to disagree :)
[image]

Comment: A scheduled flow should work.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but technically it could end up missing records in some edge cases. I'd say it'd be more reliable to use a Record Triggered Flow with a Scheduled Path set to either five days after Last Modified Date, or you could even use the formula field you created to make sure it fires either five or seven days afterwards (business days). Alternatively, your Scheduled Flow could just query records directly, rather than relying on a formula, which also involves a full table scan, which may eventually run into other limits.

Comment: Thank you. Maybe is it possible to elaborate a little on that. I build a path and now get the error message nothing is connected to the start element.

Comment: Could you maybe have another look?

Comment: @AlexM. Yeah, I'll see what I can come up with.